# How do you extract content under header tags?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an html like so:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum 1

  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  Lorem ipsum 2

  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <b>Lorem ipsum 3</b>

  <h1>Title 4</h1>
  Lorem ipsum 4

  <h2>Title 5</h2>
  Lorem ipsum 5
</div>
```

I want to extract content under each header title and place them into an array like so:

```
[
  "Lorem ipsum 1",
  "Lorem ipsum 2",
  "<b>Lorem ipsum 3</b>",
  "Lorem ipsum 4",
  "Lorem ipsum 5"
]
```

How would I do that using regex and/or ruby? I tried playing around with `split` method, like `html_body.split(">")`, but still can't figure out how to do so correctly. What is the correct way to do it using regex and/or ruby?

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser - in case of Ruby - Nokogiri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Using Nokogiri is more robust than trying from scratch.

```
require "nokogiri"

html = <<_
<div class="content">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  Lorem ipsum 1

  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  Lorem ipsum 2

  <h3>Title 3</h3>
  <b>Lorem ipsum 3</b>

  <h1>Title 4</h1>
  Lorem ipsum 4

  <h2>Title 5</h2>
  Lorem ipsum 5
</div>
_

Nokogiri::HTML(html)
.css("div")
.children
.reject{|e| e.name =~ /\Ah\d\z/}
.map{|e| e.to_html.strip}.reject(&:empty?)
```

result:

```
[
  "Lorem ipsum 1",
  "Lorem ipsum 2",
  "<b>Lorem ipsum 3</b>",
  "Lorem ipsum 4",
  "Lorem ipsum 5"
]
```

Comment: Awesome. I just tried it using your way and it works perfectly. Thank you sawa! :)

Comment: Hi Sawa, I'm having some trouble extracting multiple line bodies and posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293459/extracting-multiple-line-content-under-header-tags

Comment: Your problem is not about multiple line, it is about multiple nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
/(?<=<\/h\d>\n).*/gm
```

and trim the match to get the desired output.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/mX5eH6/1)

Comment: Great. Thank you Amit :) Is there a way to match with multiple lines in the body as well? For example: http://rubular.com/r/gZjIV8W7Oj